Formal language Concatenation is a binary operation?
In formal Language theory does the concatenation of two strings can be seen as a binary operation?
If so, what are the domain and codomain?
You might think that if given $\mathcal{A}$ alphabet then $W = \{x : x \text{ is a string} \}$ then  $* : W \times W \longrightarrow W$ is the concatenation. The problem is that how do you build $W$?
From the book I'm reading $W = \bigcup_{i =1}^{\infty} W_i$ with $W_0 = \{\lambda\}$ and $W_i = \{ x : |x| = i \}$ with $|x|$ the length if $x$.
$W$ is built as the union of all the sets that has strings of any lenght.
Then can we see $|.|$ as a function? It is clearly that the codomain is $\mathbb{N}$. But what is the domain? $W$?!!
I guess the question is whether is the concatenation $*$ or the length $|.|$, are they maps, functions, morphisms or not?? what are the domain and codomain of both?

Qiachu's answer is great, but I want to add that I love your question --- it shows that you're really trying to think through the meanings and logical consistency of the fundamentals as you learn them, and that's a great thing to do!

Thanks for your comment! I'm very invested in Mathematical Logic. It is a very exciting journey.

What is this question asking?

@user3840170 I stumbled into a circular definition, but was fixed by Qiaochu Yuan solution. check out the Münchhausen trilemma. (The spanish version is more explicit in my opinion.)

Given an alphabet $A$ you can construct the set of words of length $n$ as $W_n = A^n$, the cartesian product of $n$ copies of $A$ with itself. Then the set of (finite) words
$$W = \bigsqcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} W_n = \bigsqcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A^n$$
can be constructed as the disjoint union of these (so here for us $\mathbb{N}$ includes zero). Concatenation is a binary operation $W \times W \to W$ on $W$ built out of taking the cartesian product, and length is a function $W \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by the property that it takes the value $n$ on $W_n$.
(This exhibits $W$ as the free monoid on $A$.)
I'm not quite sure what you're confused about but I think it's that the statements you've written down, although true, are circular as a definition of the set of words, since $W_n$ is defined in terms of the set of words already. The above is a non-circular definition in set theory.
Edit: You might also wonder whether we need to say "disjoint union" above or whether we can just say "union." The issue is that depending on your precise construction of the cartesian product you may need to check whether or not $A^n$ and $A^m$ for $n \neq m$ are disjoint as sets. Even if that happened to be true it would be a silly and irrelevant implementation detail, it's not "supposed" to happen. Using the disjoint union lets us ignore this; the result does not meaningfully depend on the precise construction of the cartesian product, in the sense that given any two such constructions the corresponding versions of $W$ are naturally in bijection with each other.

Nice! I can buy the fact that words can be seen a n-tuples. But does $W$ has to be the disjoint union of $A^n$? cannot the normal union  do the trick too?

@Alejo: I just added a comment about this! I'll edit it into the answer.

Yes, the problem was that all definitions where very circular and I started to panic. Your solution is perfect. Thank you.

If $A$ is the alphabet, the free monoid over $A$ is the set $A^*$ of all words over $A$. The concatenation is simply the product in the monoid $A^*$. There is a unique monoid morphism $u \to |u|$ from $A^*$ to $({\Bbb N},+)$
such that $|a| = 1$ for each letter $a \in A$. The integer $|u|$ is called the length of $u$.
